# Can these new etymological pairs of PIE roots be true?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, cognates, roots

I find a paper containing new lists of cognates on PIE root level, and don't know such phenomena or rules are convincing or not, the list follows below:

> **1. The voiceless stop vs. voiced aspirated stop alternation3**
>
> 1.1. *dʰrei̯k(ʰ)- vs. *dʰrei̯gʰ-: ‘hair, bristle’
>
> 1.2. *h₁eḱ(s)- vs. *h₁eǵʰ(s)-: ‘out’
>
> 1.3. *(h₂)kou̯s- vs. *gʰou̯s-: ‘hear, sound’
>
> 1.4. **h₁reu̯t- vs. *h₁reu̯dʰ-: ‘red’
>
> 1.5. *ḱ(e)rd- vs. *ǵʰ(e)rd-: ‘heart’
>
> 1.6. *kap- vs. *gʰabʰ-: ‘grab, take’
>
> 1.7. *kaput- vs. *k(a)ubʰut-: ‘head’
>
> 1.8. *ḱel-1 vs. *ǵʰel(h₂)-/*gʰel-1: ‘warm, bright, shine, yellow, green, blue, sun’
>
> 1.9. *ḱelb- vs. *ǵʰelb-/gʰelb-: ‘help’
>
> 1.10. *ḱer-2 vs. *gʰer-: ‘grow’
>
> 1.11 . *ḱe-/*ḱo- vs. *gʰe-/*gʰo-: ‘this, that’
>
> 1.12. *ko(m)- vs. **gʰo(m)-: ‘with, together’
>
> 1.13. *lei̯p-1 vs. *Hlei̯bʰ-: ‘smear, stick’
>
> 1.14. *lei̯t-1, *lei̯t(ʰ)-29 vs. *lai̯dʰ-: ‘be disgusted, suffer, hurt’
>
> 1.15. *lento-12 vs. *lendʰ-1: ‘flexible, fluid’
>
> 1.16. *mei̯k- vs. *mei̯gʰ-: ‘close the eyes’
>
> 1.17. *n̥ter- vs. *n̥dʰer-: ‘under, below’
>
> 1.18. *pel-9 vs. *bʰel-1: ‘white, shine, burn’
>
> 1.19. *per-2/*per-2B vs. *bʰer-1: ‘over, go over, carry over’
>
> 1.20. *pleu̯- vs. *bʰleu̯-: ‘run, flow, swim’
>
> 1.21 . *pleu̯k- vs. **pleu̯gʰ-: ‘fly’
>
> 1.22. *plou̯- vs. *b(ʰ)lou̯-: ‘flea’
>
> 1.23. *rep- vs. *rebʰ-: ‘grab, rip out, be taken, be furious’
>
> 1.24. *sek-2, *skei̯- vs. *segʰ-, **sgʰei̯-: ‘cut, separate’
>
> 1.25. *(s)keu̯p- vs. *(s)keu̯b(ʰ)-: ‘bundle, flock’
>
> 1.26. *telek- vs. *teleǵʰ-13: ‘hit’
>
> 1.27. *ters- vs. *dʰer-2: ‘dry’
>
> 1.28. *-tlom vs. *-dʰlom, *-trom vs. *-dʰrom: instrumental suffixes
>
> 1.29. *tragʰ- vs. *dʰ(e)ragʰ-: ‘pull, bring’
>
> 1.30. *u̯ekʷ- vs. *u̯egʷʰ-: ‘speak, speak solemnly’
>
> **2. The *l/*n alternation**
>
> 2.1. *al-1, *ol- vs. *an-2, *on-: ‘this, that’
>
> 2.2. *mel-4 vs. *men(e)gʰ-: ‘much’
>
> 2.3. *pleu̯- vs. *pneu̯-: ‘flow, blow’
>
> 2.4. *-sleh₂ vs. *-sneh₂: object indicative suffixes
>
> 2.5. *su̯el- vs. *su̯en-: ‘sun’
>
> 2.6. *u̯el-2 vs. *u̯en-1/*u̯enH-: ‘want, love’
>
> 2.7. *u̯el-8 vs. *u̯en-2: ‘hurt, hit’
>
> **3. Co-occurrence of both alternations**
>
> 3.1. *gal-2 vs. *gʰel- vs. *kel-6 vs. *kan-/*ḱan-: ‘call, cry, sing’

The data is from ["Consonantal Alternations in Indo-European Roots: Diatopic and/or Diachronic Variants or Functional Mechanism?"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322721257_Consonantal_Alternations_in_Indo-European_Roots_Diatopic_andor_Diachronic_Variants_or_Functional_Mechanism?enrichId=rgreq-cc79053788bc6478c2b94e45b04cf6e6-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzMyMjcyMTI1NztBUzo1ODcwMzE0NzQzNzI2MTZAMTUxNjk3MDYxODYzOA%3D%3D&el=1_x_2&_esc=publicationCoverPdf), published by "[Journal of Indo-European Studies The 45 Vol., 2017](http://www.jies.org/docs/jies_index/Vol45.html)"

Comment: I do not know for others but r/n and l/n alterations at the end on the stem are well known, this is common in the most ancient stems. In nominative it would keep l or r while in orther cases  and in adjectives it would change to n. Example: u̯odr/u̯ednos (water/watery)

Comment: See [heteroclitic stems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Heteroclitic_stems) for (a little) more information on these.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly but we're delving here into the language that went before proto-Indo-European.
The alternations are ones found in other languages. For example the l/n alternation is found in Ancient Egyptian and the k/gh is reminiscent (although different) to Verner's alternations in Germanic, so the theory is not far-fetched.
There may be the relic of the l/n alternation in Germanic in the word for 'sun' (English 'sun' but Gothic 'sauil'), which indicates there may have still been an l/n grammatical alternation in proto-germanic.
Given the number of pairs found by Bizzocchi it looks likely and I'm sure that many theories can be built around this evidence.

Comment: The consonant alternation involving voiceless stop and voiced aspirated stop is unknown to me, would you provide some reference of this rule? And I find another paper having similar claims but more difficult to read due to my lack of knowledge of PPIE, https://www.academia.edu/27643519/Prenasalized_stops_in_IE_and_possible_semantic_developments_from_bite_to_take

Comment: As far as I know there is no 'rule'. My reading of what the author you quoted is saying is that he is listing word pairs in the hope that a future philologist will discover a rule. What I said above is that it is reminiscent of word pairs in other languages so is not far-fetched.